# How to view squashed commits as branches?

Tags: git

When I view my log tree with the command

```
git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

I see next log messages:

```
* 5bfe287 Squashed commit of the following:
```

**Is there an option like `--expand-squash` to see such commits as branch?**

```
git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --expand-squash

* 5bfe287 Squashed commit of the following:
|\  
| * b10cbf5 Do not debug befer/after DB:: actions
| * 453e963 Debug debugger: implemented tescase for returning from debugger
|/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No,<sup>1</sup> there is no way to do this.  A squash merge is not a merge at all.  It is a new commit that copies the effect of combining a series of older commits, as if you had used `git cherry-pick -n` on each of the older commits in sequence.  The new squash commit has no link to the old commits, and the old commits may not even be in the repository (they may never have been sent to you, or, if you made those commits yourself earlier, they are only still in your repository if you kept them around, e.g., via reflogs or on the old branch or whatever).

Squash "merges" are good for some purposes, but should not be used to hide individual commits that you might want to see again later.  Use a real merge for those.  This is what a real merge is for: to retain the actual history.  It is the opposite of what a squash merge is for: to discard the actual history, replacing it with a new, simpler history.

---

<sup>1</sup>This assumes that the commit in question is one made with the "squash merge" feature.  If it is a real merge, you would probably already see the history you care about, though.

Comment: some projects require I do squashed commits to them, but when I merge this brunch into my master and then merge remote branche with squashed commit I may get merge conflicts (((

Answer (score 0):

Your squash commit seems to have been created using the `--squash` option of the merge command. This created an automatic commit message which contains everything you need but is, unfortunately, multi-line. The `--pretty=oneline` option of your `git log` hides subsequent lines in the commit message.

A workaround without having to change the history would be to remove the `--pretty=oneline` option from the `git log`:

```
git log --graph --decorate --abbrev-commit
```

It's a lot less readable and might defeat the purpose of veiwing the history as a graph, but it does give you the full multi-line commit message.

Comment: No, I am not interested in multi-line commit message view, that is why I use `--pretty=oneline `

Comment: You may have misinterpreted my answer. A multi-line commit message is what you already have in your history.